# Omitting Numbers with regex

Tags: python, regex

This is, I fear, frighteningly simple, but I can't make it work (and I can't find the answer through a search). I am scraping a website for all words in italics (the ones I want are in groups of two words--they are binomial scientific names), but I don't want any numbers returned.

The regex I used : `<i>(.+?)</i>`

worked great but it pulled the numbers. I thought using `\D` would work, but it didn't. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show an example of input ? Also what language are you using ? Python ?

Comment: Since I didn't get any reply. I will leave the following solution: match everything using `<i>(.+?)</i>`, after that loop through group 1 and replace using `\D` with empty string.

Comment: The problem occurs when there is something like `<i>a1b2</i>`. I would think that the OP is expecting `ab` as output. The easiest way is to use 2 regexes.

Comment: Oh, so basically just wants to strip integers from any string inside the tags. Gotcha.

Comment: @hwnd well that's my interpretation, there is a possibility that the OP has something else in mind :P

Comment: @HamZa I'm confused because here's a list of [binomial names](http://animals.about.com/od/animal-facts/a/animals-atoz-scientific.htm) for example.. I see no numbers? =P

Comment: @hwnd That's why input would have helped [...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brfxxccxxmnpcccclllmmnprxvclmnckssqlbb11116#Protest_names)

Comment: So sorry for my omissions, oversights and general ignorance. I'm new to Python, and it is Python I am using. Using two regexes had not occurred to me as a possibility. Yes, I basically want to strip integers from any string inside the tags. The expected output are scientific names (e.g., Homo Sapiens), but one of the sites from which I am scraping data is also returning lengths of specimens in integers. I'd like to omit those so the outfile is clean (just a list of the scientific names). I hope that makes sense.

Comment: wew, i'm scare of python, put the tag on instead just regex please :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Yes, I basically want to strip integers from any string inside the tags.

Python's `re.findall` looping through your matches replacing number characters should work for you.

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(?<=<i>).*?(?=</i>)')

for names in re.findall(pattern, htmltext):
    print re.sub(r'[0-9]', '', names)
```

To find the matches that do not contain numbers:

```
matches = re.findall(r'(?<=<i>)[^0-9]*(?=</i>)', htmltext)
print matches
```

Comment: lol after reading this answer I realised that I made a mistake in the comments, I said to use `\D` while it's the contrary +1

Comment: Thanks. I'm really lost now. I'm going to have back up several steps and try to re-learn this so what you're suggesting makes sense to me. Thank you so much.

Comment: Okay. So I'm scraping my data from a website. Then I'm using: regex = '<i>(.+?)</i>'
 pattern = re.compile(regex)
 data = re.findall (pattern,htmltext,)
 print data

Comment: That did something like what I asked, but it didn't yield the result I need. I think I need to rethink this. The trouble is that there are two types of things in italics on the webpage, and I only want to scrape one of them. I want the italicized binomial scientific names and not the italicized specimen length. The former is coded like this: <div id="Scientific_name" style="width:100px;"><i>Homo sapiens</i></div> and the latter is coded like this: <div id="specimen_Size" style="width:100px;"><i>166 CM</i></div>

Comment: But do the names have numbers in them?

Comment: No. The binomials do not have numbers in them.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much. Now I'm going to go back and figure out why that worked.

Answer (score -1):

I think it works. You can try so.
    +^[0-9]

Comment: Your syntax is off, the non-class notation is `[^0-9]+?`. Given the question, `[^0-9<]+` would work even better.